# Can I format a DataGridText column in a DataGrid as hyperlink?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, syncfusion

I have a DataGrid in my XAML code defined this:

```
        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="PasswdVw" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding PassWrd}"
                           SelectedRow="{Binding SelPassRws, Mode=TwoWay}" GridLinesVisibility="Both" SelectionMode ="Multiple" NavigationMode="Row"
                           Margin="20,20,0,0" HeaderRowHeight="35" ColumnWidthMode="Fill"
                           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" SortingMode="Single">
        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.DefaultStyle>
            <syncfusion:DataGridStyle RowBackground="white" SelectedRowTextColor="White" SelectionBackground="blue"
                                      HeaderRowBackground="#C5C5C5" HeaderRowTextColor="Black" HeaderRowFontAttributes="Bold"/>
        </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.DefaultStyle>
        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
            <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn MappingName="PassId" Width="0"/>
            <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn MappingName="PassUsrname" HeaderText="User Name"/>
            <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn MappingName="PassPassword" HeaderText="Password"
                                            Width="150"/>
            <syncfusion:DataGridTextColumn MappingName="PassUrl" HeaderText="Web Site"/>
        </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
    </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
```

And when I run my program the column with MappingName="PassUrl" always fills with web site addresses. However, they only display as text strings. Is there a way to convert those strings into a clickable hyperlink?

Also, is there a way to make columns manually resizable so the user can resize each column at runtime based on their needs?

Comment: You can style them any way you want, and you can also define behavior for selecting a row.  You may be able to add a tap gesture recognizer to an individual cell

Comment: Ok Jason. Can you be more specific. Like how do I convert the plain text to hyperlink in my DataGrid control located in my XAML file.

Comment: there is no magic setting that will automatically create an HTML style hyperlink.  You can probably achieve something similar with a combination of formatting and event handlers or commands.  It will require some trial and error.  Read the [docs](https://help.syncfusion.com/maui/datagrid/overview).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TapGestureRecognizer` to create the hyperlink.

Here is the steps to create the hyperlink:

- Set the `TextColor` and `TextDecoration` properties of the Label or Span.
- Add a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the GestureRecognizers collection of
  the Label or Span, whose Command property binds to a `ICommand`, and
  whose `CommandParameter` property contains the URL to open.
- Define the `ICommand` that will be executed by the
  `TapGestureRecognizer`.
- Write the code that will be executed by the `ICommand`.

Here is the code sample:

```
   <Label>
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                <Span Text="Alternatively, click " />
                <Span Text="here"
                      TextColor="Blue"
                      TextDecorations="Underline">
                    <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                                              CommandParameter="https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/" />
                    </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                </Span>
                <Span Text=" to view .NET MAUI documentation." />
            </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
```

When the hyperlink is tapped, the TapGestureRecognizer will respond by executing the `ICommand` defined by its `Command` property. In addition, the URL specified by the `CommandParameter` property will be passed to the `ICommand` as a parameter.

The code-behind for the XAML page contains the `TapCommand` implementation:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    // Launcher.OpenAsync is provided by Essentials.
    public ICommand TapCommand => new Command<string>(async (url) => await Launcher.OpenAsync(url));

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```